# PAI tutorial example failed to run. With '[ExitCode]: 177'

Tags: tensorflow, openpai

I was following the PAI job [tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/pai/blob/master/job-tutorial/README.md).

Here's my job's config:

```
{
  "jobName": "yuan_tensorflow-distributed-jobguid",
  "image": "docker.io/openpai/pai.run.tensorflow",
  "dataDir": "hdfs://10.11.3.2:9000/yuan/sample/tensorflow",
  "outputDir": "$PAI_DEFAULT_FS_URI/yuan/tensorflow-distributed-jobguid/output",
  "codeDir": "$PAI_DEFAULT_FS_URI/path/tensorflow-distributed-jobguid/code",
  "virtualCluster": "default",
  "taskRoles": [
    {
      "name": "ps_server",
      "taskNumber": 2,
      "cpuNumber": 2,
      "memoryMB": 8192,
      "gpuNumber": 0,
      "portList": [
        {
          "label": "http",
          "beginAt": 0,
          "portNumber": 1
        },
        {
          "label": "ssh",
          "beginAt": 0,
          "portNumber": 1
        }
      ],
      "command": "pip --quiet install scipy && python code/tf_cnn_benchmarks.py --local_parameter_device=cpu --batch_size=32 --model=resnet20 --variable_update=parameter_server --data_dir=$PAI_DATA_DIR --data_name=cifar10 --train_dir=$PAI_OUTPUT_DIR --ps_hosts=$PAI_TASK_ROLE_ps_server_HOST_LIST --worker_hosts=$PAI_TASK_ROLE_worker_HOST_LIST --job_name=ps --task_index=$PAI_CURRENT_TASK_ROLE_CURRENT_TASK_INDEX"
    },
    {
      "name": "worker",
      "taskNumber": 2,
      "cpuNumber": 2,
      "memoryMB": 16384,
      "gpuNumber": 4,
      "portList": [
        {
          "label": "http",
          "beginAt": 0,
          "portNumber": 1
        },
        {
          "label": "ssh",
          "beginAt": 0,
          "portNumber": 1
        }
      ],
      "command": "pip --quiet install scipy && python code/tf_cnn_benchmarks.py --local_parameter_device=cpu --batch_size=32 --model=resnet20 --variable_update=parameter_server --data_dir=$PAI_DATA_DIR --data_name=cifar10 --train_dir=$PAI_OUTPUT_DIR --ps_hosts=$PAI_TASK_ROLE_ps_server_HOST_LIST --worker_hosts=$PAI_TASK_ROLE_worker_HOST_LIST --job_name=worker --task_index=$PAI_CURRENT_TASK_ROLE_CURRENT_TASK_INDEX"
    }
  ],
  "killAllOnCompletedTaskNumber": 2,
  "retryCount": 0
}
```

The job was succeed submitted, but failed soon, in about 4 minutes later.

And below is my 'Application Summary'.

> Start Time: 6/15/2018, 8:18:01 PM
>
> Finish Time: 6/15/2018, 8:22:31 PM
>
> Exit Diagnostics:
>
> [ExitStatus]: LAUNCHER_EXIT_STATUS_UNDEFINED [ExitCode]: 177
>   [ExitDiagnostics]: ExitStatus undefined in Launcher, maybe
>   UserApplication itself failed. [ExitType]: UNKNOWN
>   ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ [ExitCustomizedDiagnostics]: [ExitCode]: 1 [ExitDiagnostics]:
>   Exception from container-launch. Container id:
>   container_1529064439409_0003_01_000005 Exit code: 1 Stack trace:
>   ExitCodeException exitCode=1:  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Shell output: [ERROR] EXIT signal received in yarn container, exiting
>   ...
>
> Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
>
> ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ [ExitCustomizedDiagnostics]:
>
> [worker](https://github.com/Microsoft/pai/blob/master/job-tutorial/README.md): TASK_COMPLETED: [TaskStatus]: { "taskIndex" : 1,
>   "taskRoleName" : "worker", "taskState" : "TASK_COMPLETED",
>   "taskRetryPolicyState" : { "retriedCount" : 0, "succeededRetriedCount"
>   : 0, "transientNormalRetriedCount" : 0,
>   "transientConflictRetriedCount" : 0, "nonTransientRetriedCount" : 0,
>   "unKnownRetriedCount" : 0 }, "taskCreatedTimestamp" : 1529065083290,
>   "taskCompletedTimestamp" : 1529065346772, "taskServiceStatus" : {
>   "serviceVersion" : 0 }, "containerId" :
>   "container_1529064439409_0003_01_000005", "containerHost" :
>   "10.11.1.9", "containerIp" : "10.11.1.9", "containerPorts" :
>   "http:2938;ssh:2939;", "containerGpus" : 15, "containerLogHttpAddress"
>   :
>   "http://10.11.1.9:8042/node/containerlogs/container_1529064439409_0003_01_000005/admin/",
>   "containerConnectionLostCount" : 0, "containerIsDecommissioning" :
>   null, "containerLaunchedTimestamp" : 1529065087200,
>   "containerCompletedTimestamp" : 1529065346768, "containerExitCode" :
>   1, "containerExitDiagnostics" : "Exception from
>   container-launch.\nContainer id:
>   container_1529064439409_0003_01_000005\nExit code: 1\nStack trace:
>   ExitCodeException exitCode=1: \n\tat
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)\n\tat
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)\n\tat
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)\n\tat
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)\n\tat
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)\n\tat
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)\n\tat
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n\nShell output: [ERROR] EXIT
>   signal received in yarn container, exiting ...\n\n\nContainer exited
>   with a non-zero exit code 1\n", "containerExitType" : "UNKNOWN" }
>   [ContainerDiagnostics]: Container completed
>   container_1529064439409_0003_01_000005 on HostName 10.11.1.9.
>   ContainerLogHttpAddress:
>   http://10.11.1.9:8042/node/containerlogs/container_1529064439409_0003_01_000005/admin/
>   AppCacheNetworkPath:
>   10.11.1.9:/var/lib/hadoopdata/nm-local-dir/usercache/admin/appcache/application_1529064439409_0003
>   ContainerLogNetworkPath:
>   10.11.1.9:/var/lib/yarn/userlogs/application_1529064439409_0003/container_1529064439409_0003_01_000005
>   ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ [AMStopReason]:Task [worker](https://github.com/Microsoft/pai/blob/master/job-tutorial/README.md) Completed and KillAllOnAnyCompleted
>   enabled.

Found more log details:

```
[INFO] hdfs_ssh_folder is hdfs://10.11.3.2:9000/Container/admin/yuan_tensorflow-distributed-2/ssh/application_1529064439409_0450
[INFO] task_role_no is 0
[INFO] PAI_TASK_INDEX is 1
[INFO] waitting for ssh key ready
[INFO] waitting for ssh key ready
[INFO] ssh key pair ready ...
[INFO] begin to download ssh key pair from hdfs ...
[INFO] start ssh service
 * Restarting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd       [80G 
[74G[ OK ]
[INFO] USER COMMAND START

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code/tf_cnn_benchmarks.py", line 38, in <module>
    import benchmark_storage
ImportError: No module named benchmark_storage
[DEBUG] EXIT signal received in docker container, exiting ...
```

**Conclusion:**

**The code was incompleted, some dependencies were needed.
Below I provide a working job config.**

```
{
  "jobName": "tensorflow-cifar10",
  "image": "openpai/pai.example.tensorflow",

  "dataDir": "/tmp/data",
  "outputDir": "/tmp/output",

  "taskRoles": [
    {
      "name": "cifar_train",
      "taskNumber": 1,
      "cpuNumber": 8,
      "memoryMB": 32768,
      "gpuNumber": 1,
      "command": "git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models && cd models/research/slim && python download_and_convert_data.py --dataset_name=cifar10 --dataset_dir=$PAI_DATA_DIR && python train_image_classifier.py --batch_size=64 --model_name=inception_v3 --dataset_name=cifar10 --dataset_split_name=train --dataset_dir=$PAI_DATA_DIR --train_dir=$PAI_OUTPUT_DIR"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you find something in container log?
http://10.11.2.36:8042/node/containerlogs/container_1529064439409_0367_01_000004/admin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the log of a failed job will not be erased. It is moved to hdfs after the job completes.

From your log, it looks like the code misses some files. please download the whole folder of the benchmarks, instead of just one or two files (like cnn benchmark).

Comment: You are right, some dependencies were missed. I have updated my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you need look into the logs of all workers especially the first exited container to see what happens there because any container exited will cause Launcher to stop the job earlier, thus you could see the "EXIT signal received in yarn container" message in application diagnostic content.

Comment: Thanks, but seems PAI would clean the job container immediately. I have to keep refreshing the log output.